# Integral of Simple Functions converges to Integral of Measurable Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a measurable function and $E_{n,m} = \{x : \frac{m}{2^n} \leq f(x) < \frac{m+1}{2^n} \}$.

Prove:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{2^n} \mu(E_{n,m}) \to \int f \, d\mu$$

Attempted Proof:

We wish to show for any $\phi \leq f$, $\phi$ simple, there exists $\varphi$ of the form $$\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{m}{2^n} \mathbb{1}_{(E_{n,m})},$$ another simple function such that $\int \phi \leq \int \varphi$, which will imply the supremums over all such simple functions are equal.

Let $\phi  = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{r} a_i \mathbb{1}_{(A_i)}$ Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $M = \max \limits_{i=1, \ldots, n} \{\mu(A_i)\}.$ Let $\tilde{\epsilon} = \min \{a_i, \frac{\epsilon}{nM} \}$. Then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{r} (a_i-\tilde{\epsilon}) \mu(A_i) > \int \phi \, d\mu - \epsilon.$$

Now choose $2^{-N} < \tilde{\epsilon}$ so for each $a_i$ we have (wlog)

$$\frac{m-1}{2^N} \leq a_i -\tilde{\epsilon} < \frac{m}{2^N}.$$

Thus if $$\varphi = \sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{m}{2^N} \mathbb{1}_{(E_{N,m})}$$ for sufficiently large $k$, then

$$\int \phi \, d\mu - \epsilon < \int \varphi \, d\mu$$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ implies $\int \phi \leq \int \varphi$. This implies the convergence.

**Anything wrong here? any poor assumptions that break this proof? an easier method to proving this?**

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler way to do this by introducing some more machinery. Let $f_n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{m}{2^n}\chi_{E_{n,m}}$. Show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise and then that $f_n$ is monotonically increasing. Then apply the [Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: we didn't have mct available :/

Comment: Ah okay I didn't realize. I doubt there's a much simpler proof that proceeds merely from the definition of the Lebesgue integral. It seems to me like a very natural place to apply mct.